# Validation levels in Domain Driven Design

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design

I am working on a web application where we are implementing **DDD** concepts and we have structured our website as **N-tier** application with the following tiers(API,Service layer,Business layer,DataAccess layer).

We do validate our domain models to ensure consistency and integrity of our models and aggregates but I have some doubts whether should we add validation on Api models(using Data Annotations cause we are using **asp.net** and **web Api**).

My question is somehow weird but should we do validation at Api level or it will be considered as duplication  and maybe will lead to difference in validation from the validation performed on the domain level?

Comment: Hello, did I answer your question? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of validation and some validations should be done in some layers and other validations in other layers. So:

I keep the core business rules in the `Aggregates`, in the `Domain` Layer. An example is `the account balance can not be negative`.

Low level rules like `email address must be valid` are kept inside the `command's` constructor, also inside the `Domain layer`, because `commands` are part of the `Domain` layer.

Authorization checks, like `owner` can `delete` own `activities` or `admin` can `delete` any `activity` are done in the `Application` layer.

Note: this applies to the following architecture: Presentation (like REST endpoints, MVC), Application, Domain and Infrastructure.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you, but have concerns about the validation in the `constructors` for me I would prefer to move this validation into the factory method. And I'll not expose the constructor without factory methods

Comment: @WahidBitar it's almost the same